# Беззвучный фрейм. ffmpeg

Tags: c++, ffmpeg

На случай, если RTP пакет с чьи-то фремом задерживается\потерялся, надо вместо него записать пустой, а лучше беззвучный. С пустым фреймом есть некоторые проблемы: (отправка RTP пакета с заголовком, но без данных). Есть какой-нибудь вариант создать такой фрейм? (имеется ввиду декодированный, который я потом кодирую)

Comment: Если у вас PCM декодированный знаковый (S16LE, S - signed), то просто создаёте AVPacket где data будет нужного размера заполненная просто нулями. Если безнаковый, то значением 2^(bits-1), где bits-битность семпла (16, 32 и т.д.). Не знаю, как вы будете оцениваться, сколько у вас семплов потерялось, но если, допустим, потерялось 100мс семплов, то количество потерянных байт посчитать можно так: `count = 100 * bits/8 * freq * ch_count / 1000`, в случае 48000 частоты дискретизации (freq), количестве каналов 2 (ch_count) и битности семпла 16, получится: `100 * 16/2 * 48000 * 2 / 1000 = 76800`bytes.

Comment: С этим лучше подскажут те, кто со звуком работает. Давайте скопирую совет в ответ, раз помогло.

Comment: @MonahTuk мне помог частный случай вашего ответа: я знаю приблизительный размер пакета, который должен приходить(замеряю среднее). И инициализирую AVpacket этого размера, который затем декодируется в фрейм и уже этот фрейм идет в фильтр.

Comment: гм, скорее всего тут нужно считать более внимательно. И возможно, из-за того, что вы "восстанавливаете" не точное число семлов и появляется железный звук.

Comment: @MonahTuk не, из-за этого может появиться только небольшой треск или щелчек в конце пакета (так как происходит скачек колебаний с какого-то бита на нулевой(нулевой - так как дальше нет данных для проигрывания и они заменяются нулевыми байтами)), а металлический звук - следствие алгоритмов микширования (побитовое сложение, взятие среднего и тд.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если у вас PCM декодированный знаковый (S16LE, S - signed), то просто создаёте `AVPacket` где `data` будет нужного размера и заполнена просто нулями.

Если без знаковый, то значением `2^(bits-1)`, где bits-битность семпла (16, 32 и т.д.).

Не знаю, как вы будете оцениваться, сколько у вас семплов потерялось, но если, допустим, потерялось 100 мс семплов, то количество потерянных байт посчитать можно так:

```
count = 100 * bits/8 * freq * ch_count / 1000
```

В случае частоты  дискретизации (freq) равно 48000 Hz, количестве каналов 2 (ch_count) и битности семпла 16, получится:

```
100 * 16/2 * 48000 * 2 / 1000 = 76800
```

байт. Что бы получить число семплов - поделите это значение на `bits/2`.